Why does internal mic not working on Ubuntu 24.04?
I have Redmibook 15 Pro 2023, recently installed Ubuntu 24.04 instead of Ubuntu 23.10. On 23.10 internal mic was working, now it is not detecting. Internal speakers are working ok, mic from headphones via jack is also ok.
tried restarting alsa like this:
sudo alsa force-reload

tried configuring pavucontrol, mic is neither detected there
set /etc/asound.conf like this:                              pcm.!default { type hw card 1 device 0 } ctl.!default { type hw card 1 }
uncommented this row in /etc/pulse/default.pa
load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:1,0 

then set it to
load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:0,0

here is some info about system
System: Host: ofuzeev-Redmi-Book-Pro-15-2023 Kernel: 6.8.0-31-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: GNOME v: 46.0 Distro: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (Noble Numbat) Machine: Type: Laptop System: XIAOMI product: Redmi Book Pro 15 2023 Audio: Device-1: AMD Rembrandt Radeon High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel Device-2: AMD ACP/ACP3X/ACP6x Audio Coprocessor driver: snd_pci_acp6x Device-3: AMD Family 17h/19h HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel API: ALSA v: k6.8.0-31-generic status: kernel-api Server-1: PipeWire v: 1.0.5 status: active Server-2: PulseAudio v: 16.1 status: active
ofuzeev@ofuzeev-Redmi-Book-Pro-15-2023:~$ arecord -l
**** Список CAPTURE устройств **** карта 1: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], устройство 0: CX8070 Analog [CX8070 Analog] Подустройства: 0/1 Подустройство №0: subdevice #0
